# Not being able to apply styles to first child with styled components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

So I'm iterating over a collection that's also nested:

```
  departments.map(({ departmentName, listings }: Department) =>
    <DepartmentContainer key={departmentName}>
      <DepartmentName>{departmentName}</DepartmentName>
      <JobsContainer>
        {listings.map(({ title, id, location }: Job) =>
          <Card
            key={id}
            id={id}
            title={title}
            location={location}
            onClick={(e: React.SyntheticEvent<MouseEvent>) => {
              e.preventDefault();
              history.push(`/company/careers/${id}`);
              handleOpen();
            }}
          />,
        )}
      </JobsContainer>
    </DepartmentContainer>
```

and in my styled component, I'm trying to apply a `border-top` to each `DepartmentContainer` **except** the first one:

```
const DepartmentContainer = styled.div`
  &:not(:first-child) {
    border-top: 1px solid ${borderGray};
  };
`;
```

I've tried something like:

```
border-top: 1px solid ${borderGray};
  &:first-child {
    border-top: none;
    border-top-color: transparent;
  }
```

as well as `first-of-type`. Nothing seems to work. And the styles aren't getting applied anywhere else... any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this correctly, you might need to add your stylings onto the parent of `DepartmentContainer` in order to get your css to apply on `DepartmentContainer`